# Jenkins - "Failed to mkdirs", when starting a build

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2003

I am trying to set up Jenkins on a remote machine. I have it installed and ready to go but when I try to run my job, I get the following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1093)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1247)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1740)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: tS@web.com
Error sending to the following VALID addresses: tS@web.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does anybody have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Did you notice the workspace path `Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"`? Have you set your `JENKINS_HOME` variable? If not, what is the value of _Home directory_ in `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System` page?

Answer (score 2):

This line tells you everything:

`Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"`

That above is not a valid path no matter how you look at it. Without seeing your configuration (and you are not providing any...) we can only guess where you messed up.

So, let's guess:

- `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\` is `JENKINS_HOME` on Windows.
- A workspace would usually be `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\[jobname]\workspace` i.e `%JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\%JOB_NAME%\workspace`
- Your workspace path has neither an (obvious) jobname, nor the word `workspace`. So you've definitely tried to alter the workspace location.
- You pasted the line `"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"` (as is, with quotes) *somewhere* where you shouldn't have. Let's keep guessing.

### Probable guess:

- Under **Job Configuration** -> **Advanced Project Options** -><kbd>**Advanced...**</kbd> button, there is a an entry titled **Use custom workspace**
- If you pasted `"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"` in there, with quotes, it's not taking it as absolute path, and thinks it's a relative path, and relative paths start from `%JENKINS_HOME%`, which would explain your `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"` error
- You should paste your desired custom workspace without quotes, like this `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli`, and it will work.

### An alternative

- Alternatively, under **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> <kbd>**Advanced...**</kbd> button, there is an entry titled **Workspace Root Directory**.
- My **guess** is, you have something like `${JENKINS_HOME}"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\pbnb_cli"` in there. This would explain your current state.
- You should fix it to default value of `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace`